# Copy File To Finder Clipboard Using Bash/Applescript

Tags: bash, macos, scripting, applescript

When using Finder, you can select a file and Command+C to copy the file itself to the clipboard, allowing you to easily paste it into another directory, or even into an email, messenger, or other browser input. This is very useful for daily tasks, especially for images and screen recordings.

I'm writing scripts for improved productivity and wonder if there is a way to copy a file to the Finder clipboard in this way using bash or AppleScript?

I can't seem to find it anywhere on the web. Most command-line tools only copy the file name or file contents (if it is text).

Does anyone know of a solution to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Command line tools typically only operate with text - what specifically are you wanting to do?

Answer (score 2):

In AppleScript, you can **copy** files/folders to the clipboard using the **«class furl» references**.

```
set the clipboard to "/Users/123/Desktop/MacScripter .webloc" as «class furl»
```

Having them in the clipboard, you can **paste** this references into the application windows which can **accept them**.

**Note**: to test this, indicate Posix path of some existing file on your Mac. In my testings, I can paste the file above into any Finder.app window or New Message Window of Mail.app

Comment: If only there was a way to copy the clipboard to a variable when it contains multiple Finder items, and later restore all of those items to the clipboard.  Maybe there's a way to do it. But I've reached my wits end trying to figure out how to make it work reliably with all of the flavors originally contained for a multiple-Finder-item selection.